# Editting HTML elements within webview using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, webview, magic-mirror

I can usually figure this stuff out on my own but I'm completely lost on this one. I'm using a module for my MagicMirror called [WebView](https://github.com/Iketaki/MMM-WebView) to embed a website onto my mirror. It uses javascript, heres the base code

```
const WEBVIEW_ID = 'mmm-webview';

Module.register('MMM-WebView', {
  defaults: {
    url: 'https://www.google.com/',
    height: '640px',
    width: '480px',
    autoRefresh: false,
    autoRefreshInterval: 10 * 60 * 1000,
    loadedJS: undefined,
  },
  start: function () {
    if (this.config.autoRefresh) {
      setInterval(() => {
        //Electron.session.defaultSession.clearCache(() => {});
        //this.updateDom();
        const webview = document.getElementById(WEBVIEW_ID);
        webview.reloadIgnoringCache();
      }, this.config.autoRefreshInterval);
    }
  },
  getDom: function () {
    let wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.id = 'mmm-webview-wrapper';
    wrapper.innerHTML = `<webview id="${WEBVIEW_ID}" style="width: ${this.config.width}; height: ${this.config.height};" src="${this.config.url}"></webview>`;
    return wrapper;
  },
  notificationReceived: function (notification, payload, sender) {
    if (notification == 'MODULE_DOM_CREATED') {
      if (this.config.loadedJS && this.config.loadedJS.length > 0) {
        const webview = document.getElementById(WEBVIEW_ID);
        if (webview) {
          webview.addEventListener('did-finish-load', () => {
            webview.executeJavaScript(this.config.loadedJS);
          });
        } else {
          // TODO: Show Error
        }
      }
    }
  },
});
```

I'm trying to remove HTML div elements by ID from the webpage that im embedding when the site loads up but I just cant quite figure out how to remove elements with javascript within a 'iFrame' I guess you would call it. Any help would be appreciated!

I've tried using `document.getElementById(WEBVIEW_ID).remove();` and a few other things including jQuery in the wrapper.HTML section and haven't been able to get it working. I feel like I'm close I just don't know how to implement it into the code correctly.

Comment: Have you tried using `<webview>.executeJavaScript(code[, userGesture])`? It's a method of ElectronJS's `<webview>` element. Of course, you would need to wait for the page to fully load first.

Comment: @Seabyte I just tried that and it returned undefined... I guess I don't know how to correctly implement that into the code thats already there.

Comment: You set `config.loadedJS` to your script, that should change the DOM, right? Seems to be the purpose of that property.

Comment: @Seabyte I believe the loadedJS is to maunally load javascript on the webpage that is being embeded in the iframe because it doesn't load javascript natively.

Comment: @Seabyte I'm just trying to remove the "privacy-popup" div from the HTML within the site that i'm imbeding after the site loads in the iframe

Comment: Yes, so this does not work? And what exactly returns `undefined`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252759/discussion-between-seabyte-and-alex-harris).